# How to navigate to a different page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently redirecting users to a different page in C# with the following code;

```
Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx");
```

However, I'd like to do this in JavaScript instead.

Comment: have you used google? http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this code below

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function move() {
        window.location = "http://www.yourdomain.com";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Basically you need:

```
function goURL() {
  location.href="http://example.com"  // change url to your's
}
```

additional java-script navigation options can be found in following link: http://www.sivamdesign.com/scripts/navigate.html