# Redirecting to a struts action on clicking on a radio button

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, radio-group

I have a set of radio buttons. When one of the options is selected, I want it to redirect to a Struts action.

```
<form name=termDDL>
            <s:iterator value="filterOptions" var="a">
            <%String [] parts = request.getAttribute("a").toString().split(":"); %>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedOption" value="a" onclick="onOptionSelect()"><%=parts[0]%> <h6 style="color:gray;display: inline;"> <%=parts[1]%></h6><br>

                </s:iterator>
            </form>
```

And the javascript function *onOptionSelected()* is defined as follows just before the closing of the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onOptionSelect() {
        //document.getElementById("courseDisplayChoice").selectedIndex = 0;
        document.termDDL.action = 'displayProductsInRange.action';
        document.termDDL.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

But this is not redirecting to the struts action. And **I do not want to use a submit button** for the same. How do I accomplish this *without clicking a submit button*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970600/how-to-navigate-to-a-different-page-with-javascript

Comment: Its not redirecting to the struts action at all

Comment: There is no redirection to make. You're on a page with a given URL, and you want to go to another page with another URL. This other URL should be the URL to which the struts action is mapped. What's the problem?

Comment: I am giving the same name of the action as defined in my struts.xml, and yet it is not going into the action class's method at all

Comment: Go to the page you would like to "redirect" to. Copy the URL of that page, displayed in the address bar of the browser. Paste it in your code.

Comment: Got my mistake thanks :) After submitting my question , I tried using onSelect instead of onClick and it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location` for redirecting from client side to anywhere.

```
function onOptionSelect() {
    //document.getElementById("courseDisplayChoice").selectedIndex = 0;
    window.location = '/displayProductsInRange.action';
}
```

Comment: Not working.. Its not directing to the struts action at all

Comment: I am giving the same name of the action as defined in my struts.xml, and yet it is not going into the action class's method at all

Comment: Got my mistake thanks :) After submitting my question , I tried using onSelect instead of onClick and it was not working